# Read data from Buffer

Tags: c++

How can i access the data from a buffer?

```
int WINAPI mRecv( SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags ) {
    // Code to access the data from buffer
}
```

Comment: `buf[n]` to extract the nth byte. But make sure you don't go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [std::istream::read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read). It is used to extract characters from stream.

And if you want to iterate over the data then you can use the [std::istreambuf_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator)

```
std::string
getBufferContent(const std::string& path)
{
  std::ifstream file(path);
  std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
  return content;
}
```